# Wordpress не видит файлы плагина

Tags: php, wordpress

вкратце поясню задачу - пишу небольшой плагин для авторизации, регистрации и прочих взаимодействий пользователя с сайтом. В одной части кода, которая отвечает за логин пользователя, я хочу выполнить проверочные действия в отдельном файле в этой же директории. В форме акшен адресую на нужный файл

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="'. plugins_url('check_data.php', __FILE__) .'" method="post">
```

файл check_data.php подключен в инициализируемом файле плагина, но в этом файле не работают функции вордпресс. Получаю ошибку такого плана `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_signon() in` 
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно подключить файл check_data.php, чтобы в нем работали все функции вордпреса ?

Comment: Нужно добавить require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо инициализировать ядро WordPress. Если ваш файл check_data.php находится по пути /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/check_data.php, то в начало этого файла надо вставить строку

```
/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once dirname( dirname (dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ) . '/wp-load.php';
```

Comment: Заработало, но опять трудность)) Нужно перенаправить в зависимости от роли на разные урлы, за это у меня отвечает метод whoIs и он проверяет функцией current_user_can('administrator') итд. Но эта функция не срабатывает, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Не видя кода, я не могу понять вопрос. Задайте отдельный вопрос, опишите в нем все.